# Laravel Multiple Relations Query with Custom Conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Context**

- Person belongsToMany Courses
- Course belongsTo CourseType

Some courses have prerequisites, for example to access course C you must attend first the courses A and B.

Basically the condition is this:

```
IF (courses_prerequisites)
AND
IF(course_not_attended)
```

Courses have a *course_slug* that help to identify them.

I successfully created a query to obtain a list of students that attended a course, but I cant figure it out **a query that retrieve students who meet certain prerequisites but have not taken the course.**

This is the query i built:

```
 return Person::whereHas('studentCourses', function($query){
      $query->whereHas('courseType', function ($sub_query) {
         $sub_query->where('id_course', $this->course_slug);
      });
  })->get();
```

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
Person::whereHas('studentCourses.course_type', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id_course', $this->getPrerequisite());
    })->whereDoesntHave('studentCourses.course_type', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id_course', $this->course_type_slug); 
    })->get();
```